# Regular expression in notepad++ for replace

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to search

```
15.2.0.23-20150414.114733-8.jar
15.2.0.23-20150414.112741-3.jar
15.2.0.23-20150414.114753-5.jar
15.2.0.23-20150414.111343-8.jar
```

this pattern in my file by notepad++. Can anyone suggest the right regex? I am trying it with `20150414.11*\.jar`, but it's not working.

Comment: you missed a `.` try something like `^15\.2\.0\.23-20150414\.11.*\.jar$`

Comment: `*` matches any character in *glob* matching. Regex matching is quite different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
20150414.11*\.jar
```

would match `20150414.1.jar`, `20150414.1111111.jar` or `20150414X1.jar` (note that `.` matches any character, and `*` repeats the preceding token (`1` in this case) any number of times).

You want something like

```
20150414\.11[^.]*\.jar
```

**Explanation:**

```
20150414 # Match "20150414"
\.11     # Match ".11"
[^.]*    # Match any number of characters except dots
\.jar    # Match ".jar"
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Oops, of course you're right. Corrected.